# Can we use Square Checkout flow for android and iOS application?

Tags: android, ios, payment-gateway, square-connect

I want to use square payment gateway as check out for my android and iOS application. But according to there documentation square can be used as point on sale for android and iOS.

I want to use square's checkout flow, which is for a web platform. I want to know is it possible to implement it in a mobile app. If possible, then how to handle callback and redirect url for payment gateway and payment response.

Thanks in advance for your greater reply on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Point of Sale API is what you're looking for: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/point-of-sale-api-overview

> For a merchant using your app, the Point of Sale API payment flow
>   looks like this:
>
> 1. The merchant uses your app to determine the amount of money to
>      charge a customer.
> 2. The merchant's device quickly switches from your
>      app to Square Point of Sale, where the amount to charge is
>      pre-populated.
> 3. The merchant processes the payment with Square Point
>      of Sale.
> 4. The merchant's device switches back to your app, which
>      receives information about the result of the transaction.

Comment: I don't want to use Point of Sale. I want to use checkout flow.